# bash script to reverse line

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

So i came across this script to reverse an input line

```
#! /bin/bash  
input="${1}"  
reverse=""  
len=${#input}  
for(( i=${len}-1; i>=0; i-- ))  
do  
reverse="$reverse${input:${i}:1}"  
done  
echo "$reverse"
```

Can someone explain what #input and the for loop does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplified, your script should be like this:

```
#! bin/bash

input="${1}"    reverse=""

for   (( i=0; i<${#input}; i++ ))
do    reverse="${input:${i}:1}$reverse"
done
echo   "$reverse"
```

Assuming you place the code above in a file named `script.sh` and that you allow it to be executed: `chmod u+x script.sh`. Then, this command will work:

```
$ ./script.sh 0123456789
9876543210
```

The value of ${#input} is the length of input (the count of characters).
The loop goes character by character from start to end.
To select each character, the script is using a bash tool called Substring Expansion.
Quoting from the `man bash` (you could also access it by typing `man bash`):

> ${parameter:offset:length}
>               Substring  Expansion.   Expands  to  up  to  length characters of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.

That means that each character at position `i` is selected in turn to re-create the  string on the `reverse` variable.

But you do not need any loop or fancy coding to do this. This simple line will do exactly the same:

```
$ echo "0123456789" | rev
9876543210
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!But i still didn't quite get the use of : character here...i know its used as a path and field delimiter but why is it used here?

Comment: @sidharthanup Please read edited answer.

Comment: I don't really know why anyone would need a script like this.

Answer (score 2):

`${#str}` is the length of the value of $str. See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual.

`for ((i=j-1; i>=0; i--))` is just a C-like for loop, using the arithmetic syntax of bash. See [Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) in the manual

Answer (score 2):

1. `${#input}` is the number of characters in `$input`. 
   Sometimes, when you see `#`, it's appropriate to think "number".
2. Is it really not obvious?  The `for` loop walks through `$input`,
   one character at a time, from the end to the beginning. 
   So, for example, if `$input` is `unix tm`,
   then the `for` loop will retrieve the characters
   `m`, `t`,  , `x`, `i`, `n`, and `u` from it, and append them to `reverse`.
3. The first line should be `#!/bin/bash` — you are missing a `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, just use `getopts`. Its whole job is to take a string apart character by character and provide an API for reading that character in an output variable.

```
input='some string or something' output= OPTIND=1
while  getopts : na "-$input"
do     output=$OPTARG$output
done;  echo "$output"
```

---

```
gnihtemos ro gnirts emos
```

You don't have to count anything or index or anything. `getopts` even returns to just kill the loop as soon as you're done. It's easy.